# Why doesn't unary plus follow parenthesis

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Consider exists a function normalize which normalize an integer to it's simplest form and consider this code

```
#include <cstdio>

class Rational {
public:

    Rational(int top = 0, int bottom = 1) : t(top), b(bottom) { normalize(t, b); }
    Rational& operator +=(Rational &val) {
        t = t * val.b + val.t * b;
        b *= val.b;
        normalize(t, b);
        return val;
    }
    void Print(const char *s) const {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s = %d/%d\n", s, t, b);
    }
private:
    int t, b;
};
int main() {
    Rational r1(1, 2), r2(1, 3), r3(1, 4);
    (r1 += r2) += r3;
    r1.Print("r1");
    r2.Print("r2");
    r3.Print("r3");
    return 0;
}
```

The code is taken out of a [Technion Institute of Technology exam.](https://webcourse.cs.technion.ac.il/234122/Winter2017-2018/ho/WCFiles/w2015a.pdf) and I could not understand why would r2 change even changes."
Changing the definition to not be by reference would just create copies and nothing would change.

Comment: There is no unary `operator +` in this code.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I am talking about += operation, if not unary then I think it's called addition assignment (not sure which, language translations sometimes get tricky)

Comment: Given that operator has two operands, it's a binary operator. The `x=` operators are generally referred to as *"compound assignment operators"*.

Comment: For the record, unary plus would be e.g. the statement `+i;` for some variable `i`, which sometimes actually is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a trick question. The point is that `operator+=` returns a reference to `val` (the right hand side) instead of the left hand side `*this` as one would normally expect.

Thus `(r1 += r2)` modifies `r1`, but returns a reference to `r2`, which is then modified by the call of `operator+=` with argument `r3`.

Therefore the values that will be printed are

```
r1 = 1/2 + 1/3 = 5/6
r2 = 1/3 + 1/4 = 7/12
r3 = 1/4
```

Comment: So what would happen is:
(r1 += r2) would modify r1 to have (r1+r2).. so now
(r1+=r2)+r3 would be (r2+=r3) because it returns reference to r2 and then r2+=r3 would modify r2 and return reference to r3 (which we ignore)

and such r1 would have r1+r2 and r2 would have r2+r3?

Comment: Exactly. I've edited the answer to include the output of the program.